# Android SqliteAssetHelper copy user saved data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-assets

I am using SQLiteAssetHelper utility to manage the copying of the database from my asset folder. In the app, the user enters some data into the database and as soon as I upgrade the db, all the data gets deleted cause I have set `setForcedUpgrade();`. I heard you can use upgrade scripts, but I think they do not help me in this case as the data is unique for each user. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> all the data gets deleted cause I have set setForcedUpgrade();

Then do not call `setForcedUpgrade()`.

> I heard you can use upgrade scripts, but I think they do not help me in this case as the data is unique for each user.

The primary point of upgrade scripts is to allow you to upgrade the schema without harming existing data, "as the data is unique for each user".

> How can I solve this?

Use upgrade scripts. Or, override `onUpgrade()`, as you would with a regular `SQLiteOpenHelper`, as [`onUpgrade()` is not `final`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/1).

Comment: I would prefer to use setForcedUpgrade(), so I don't have to use upgrade scripts for all the db upgrades.

Comment: @qwertz: "I would prefer to use setForcedUpgrade()" -- then do not allow the user to modify the data, or do not complain about the loss of user data. This behavior of `setForcedUpgrade()` is [clearly documented](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#upgrades-via-overwrite). "so I don't have to use upgrade scripts for all the db upgrades" -- as I noted in my answer, you are welcome to override `onUpgrade()` as an alternative to using upgrade scripts in `assets/`.